# How to manage automatic restarts of multiple Clojure apps with Supervisord?

Tags: clojure, supervisord

I do not have any experience with Supervisord. If I look here:

https://tgallant.github.io/clojure/supervisord-with-clojure.html

I see this example of managing a Clojure app with Supervisord:

```
[program:blog-checker]
command= /usr/local/bin/java -jar target/blog-checker-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
directory=/usr/local/www/blog-checker
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
user=www
```

If I would like to use Supervisord to keep 3 instances of my app running, do I create 3 separate entries, or is there a way to have just this one entry, but tell it to keep 3 instances going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your application listen on a port? If so, here's an example of how you would keep four instances of a networked application running (in this case, ApiAxle's API):

```
[program:apiaxle-api]
process_name = apiaxle-api-%(process_num)s
command = apiaxle-api -f 1 -p %(process_num)s
directory = /home/apiaxle/apiaxle/api
numprocs = 4
numprocs_start = 3000
user=apiaxle
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/apiaxle/api-%(process_num)s-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/apiaxle/api-%(process_num)s-stderr.log
```

Four instances listening on ports 3000, 3001, 3002 and 3003. `$(process_num)` is a variable that represents the port.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by specifying `numprocs` and `process_name`, e.g.:

```
numprocs = 3
process_name = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
```

An unless you want to count your processes from zero, you should specify `numprocs_start` variable as well:

```
numprocs_start = 1
```

[You could find complete supervisor documentation here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html).